# <canvas> within a <div>

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a webpage and I am trying to place a canvas inside a set of div tags. However I need the canvas to be on top / a layer above the images within the div. No matter what I try or where I place the canvas  html line, I can not get it to work canvas to show above the image in div1.

First I define the styles of the div classes.

```
#div1 {width:100%; background:transparent url(img/header-bg.png) no-repeat; height:400px; position:relative;}
#div2 {width:100%; background:transparent url(img/nav-bg.png) repeat-x;}
#div3 {
height:450px;
width:100%;
position:absolute; 
background:transparent url(animation/SampleAnim_0010000.png) no-repeat 80% 0; 
}

#div4 {
height:390px; 
width:100%; 
border-bottom:10px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

Then my html

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
            <div id="div4">             

            </div><!--div4-->

        </div><!--div3-->
    </div><!--div2-->
</div><!--div1-->
```

No matter where I insert within the divs

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="220"></canvas>
```

the image set in id=div1 (img/header-bg.png) overlaps the canvas. div2, div3 and div4 are correctly overlapping div1. How can I do this with the canvas?

My canvas script looks something of the lines of

```
<script>

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
if(canvas.getContext){
    // canvas animation code here:
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var lhs = new Image();

    lhs.src = "animation/SampleAnim_0010000.png";

        ctx.drawImage(lhs, 0, 0);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have no idea if it will make a difference, but have you tried playing with the `z-index`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to be working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RnEc6/1/

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2">
        <div id="div3">
            <div id="div4">             
                <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="220"></canvas>
            </div><!--div4-->
        </div><!--div3-->
    </div><!--div2-->
</div><!--div1-->​
```

I'm thinking you have a typo somewhere or styling applying a z-index to your div or canvas elements.

Comment: Looks to be where I need to have my script tags after the canvas tags. Thanks for your help ppl.